# Stack Exchange "Badges"? Blogs etc

Tags: support, reputation, badges, profile-page, flair

Not sure if this is the correct place to pose this question but I was wandering if there's some sort of "Stack Exchange/Network" html code that I can include on my personal blog?

I think I saw one a few months ago where the user had their Stack profiles on their blog with their reputation and a link to their profile etc...

I'm looking specifically for Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for what we call "flair". If you open your user profile and then click the "flair" button at the top, you will see a page with images like this one:

[image: profile for murgatroid99 at Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites]

that have the reputation and links you are looking for.

Comment: Oh fantastic, I was hoping it was built in to my profile. Thanks for your help.